# Is there a way to update existing text in the R console?

Tags: r

I am wondering if it is possible to update existing text in the R console? E.g., if I run a function that takes a bit longer to execute, I would like to know how far along it is currently.

I could achieve this by issuing `print("at 10%")`, `print("at 20%")`, etc. at appropriate locations in the function. But this could be a relatively long output, since it produces a new line each time.

Is there a way to update the console text from the running function in a way that it updates the current line in the console and not create a new line? E.g. `>at 10%` in the console changes to `>at 20%` when appropriate.

Comment: There are some progress bar functions. Have you tried any of them yet?

Comment: May depend on your OS and environment. Windows/Mac/Linux/Terminal/RStudio etc etc

Comment: Specifically if you want to stay in base R you can check out `?txtProgressBar`

Comment: @Spacedman: looking for a general solution, if none exists at least Windows+Rstudio solution. Will check out the mentioned progress bars, thx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flushing the console works but may cause flickering. If you want a very simple text line update, then it’s sufficient to go back to the beginning of the line by printing `\r` and to overwrite the text there.

Here’s a `progress` function from the [`rcane` module](https://github.com/klmr/rcane/blob/1bb57f8a4340b6ac618f98fb9f81964caea9ab8c/system.R#L24):

```
progress <- function (x, max = 100) {
    percent <- x / max * 100
    cat(sprintf('\r[%-50s] %d%%',
                paste(rep('=', percent / 2), collapse = ''),
                floor(percent)))
    if (x == max)
        cat('\n')
}
```

Here’s a screenshot of the progress bar in action:

[image: Screenshot]

And finally, this can be wrapped nicely so that its usage is effortless:

```
map_with_progress(some_function, some_data)
```

(See the link above for an implementation; of course R’s own `txtprogressBar` is quite a bit more flexible.)

Comment: R seems to go to newline with every line of code executed? Anyway, I have used the command `progress(0, 100); Sys.sleep(1); progress(50, 100);Sys.sleep(1); progress(100, 100)` in one line of script and the output is also in one line. Thanks!

Comment: @CrtAhlin R only does that if you feed the source code lines to the interpreter one by one. If you pass them to R in one go (e.g. by `source`ing the file), it works fine – same as when using semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate this by calling CTL-L each time:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  cat("\014")        ## I clear the screen 
  cat(paste0('a',i)) ## progress message in the first coin of the console.
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Comment: This prints on a new line each time for me.  I'm running R in linux through the terminal.

Comment: @Dason I test it in Rstudio and windows :)(sorry I forget that R console is not Rstudio one) basically I am using the ascii of CTR-L maybe you should try CTRL+Alt+L  under linux and R console.

Comment: If there was a solution that doesn't clear the screen (to keep previous output, since it might be relevant), it would be preferred. But, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Although a general answer to the question of "is it possible to update text in R console" was not given, it is not necessary for my particular problem. The progress bars mentioned by Ananda and Dason in comments to my questions are a solution to the problem of tracking the status of an executing function. (Updating text would actually probably not make sense in this case, if at all possible, since sometimes there is other output from the functions, which could "hide" the updated text.)

Examples of how to implemented different progress bars are well described at:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-monitoring-the-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/

For completeness, a slightly updated example from above mentioned link of the `txtProgressBar()` (which works at least with Windows+RStudio):

```
total <- 20
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
for(i in 1:total){
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  print("Result XZY")
  # update progress bar      
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```